# Unable to select recent table name from all_tables table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, toad

I have a table which contains details of all the tables present in a particular schema. The name of the table is `"all_tables"`.  There is a column called `table_name` which contains the name of all tables.

I have a table named `"SBC_RAO_INDEX_30_05_2016_04_99"`. Here `"30_05_2016_04_99"` is date with time stamp. 
Like wise I have tables with different time stamps as shown below.

```
  SBC_RAO_INDEX_30_05_2016_04_99,
  SBC_RAO_INDEX_31_05_2016_04_99,
  SBC_RAO_INDEX_01_06_2016_04_99,
  SBC_RAO_INDEX_02_06_2016_04_99,
  SBC_RAO_INDEX_03_06_2016_04_99
```

I am trying to fetch the latest table name from all_tables using below query:

```
select * 
from all_tables 
WHERE table_name like 'SBC_RAO_INDEX%' 
and table_name not like 'SBC_RAO_INDEX_BKP%' 
order by table_name desc
```

But this query is giving me `SBC_RAO_INDEX_31_05_2016_04_99` as the first row which is not correct.

Is there any way to fetch the recent table name? Kindly help me in solving this

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
SELECT
  A.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      'SBC_RAO_INDEX_30_05_2016_04_99' AS fle
    FROM
      DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'SBC_RAO_INDEX_31_05_2016_04_99' AS fle
    FROM
      DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'SBC_RAO_INDEX_01_06_2016_04_99' AS fle
    FROM
      DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'SBC_RAO_INDEX_02_06_2016_04_99' AS fle
    FROM
      DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'SBC_RAO_INDEX_03_06_2016_04_99' AS FLE
    FROM
      DUAL
  )
  A
ORDER BY
  TO_DATE(REPLACE(SUBSTR(A.FLE,15,10),'_','/'),'DD/MM/YYYY') DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

because in LIKE the '_' is a special character,
use SUBSTR instead:

```
SELECT *
  FROM all_tables
 WHERE SUBSTR(table_name,1,13) ='SBC_RAO_INDEX'
   AND SUBSTR(table_name,15,3) <> 'BKP'
 ORDER BY table_name DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the underscore is a special character to LIKE and it matches any single character, escape it to match a literal underscore by defining an escape character like this (you need the ESCAPE clause for each LIKE) and then place that character immediately before the underscore:

```
select * 
from all_tables 
WHERE table_name like 'SBC\_RAO\_INDEX%' ESCAPE '\'
and table_name not like 'SBC\_RAO\_INDEX\_BKP%' ESCAPE '\'
order by table_name desc;
```

Note you can still use the underscore to match a single character in the same string, just escape it when you need to match a literal underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
The below query fullfilled my requirement.

select table_name from all_tables WHERE 
table_name like 'SBC_RAO_INDEX_%' 
and table_name not like 'SBC_RAO_INDEX_BKP%'
order by TO_DATE(SUBSTR(table_name,15,10),'DD/MM/YYYY') DESC;